# how to find files processed in spark file streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

i have a structured streaming app set up which is monitoring a folder in blob storage for new files and does the processing on them. It works well and i can monitor and cluster health, see the incoming records, output records etc. etc.
But i really want to see if there is any log which says file name that got processing, or x number of records from this file gets processed.

any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file names that were processed are saved in the stream's configured checkpoint such `.option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs://checkpointPath")`.

For monitoring how many input rows were actually processed by the stream, look into [StreamingQueryListener](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-StreamingQueryListener.html).